# How to merge two lists created from two queries

Tags: sql-server, merge

```
select distinct top 3 FamilyId,max(LastUpdatedOn) as LastUpdatedOn from Members
 group by FamilyId
 order by max(LastUpdatedOn) desc
```

produces:

```
FamilyId| LastUpdatedOn
933     | 2021-08-18 14:52:00
932     | 2021-08-18 14:40:00
874     | 2021-08-18 13:46:00
```

```
select top 3 Id as FamilyId,LastUpdatedOn from Families order by LastUpdatedOn desc
```

produces

```
FamilyId| LastUpdatedOn
933     |2021-08-18 14:42:00
932     |2021-08-18 14:39:00
834     |2021-08-16 03:18:00
```

How can I merge/combine the two resultant lists while maintaining the sort order according to `LastUpdatedOn` (yes there can be multiple rows with the same `FamilyId`)? I am on a hosted shared server so may not have rights to create temp tables.

Background: Table `Members` contains information about individuals, while `Families` contains family level information. Every member belongs to a family, hence `Members.FamilyId` refers to the primary key `Families.Id`. I want to get the `Families.Id` values of the last few `Families` *or* `Members` that have been modified.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @drum Basically a union of both queries, but maintaining the sort order according to `LastUpdatedOn`.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Union
ie)
select distinct top 3 FamilyId,max(LastUpdatedOn) as LastUpdatedOn from Members
group by FamilyId
order by max(LastUpdatedOn) desc
Union
select top 3 Id as FamilyId,LastUpdatedOn from Families order by LastUpdatedOn desc

This returns all 6 records.

Are you expecting this?

Comment: Yes, but union loses the sort order. So I converted both queries to CTEs and I could sort the results in the `UNION`.